# Do you need to place a knockout.js binding handler in jQuery's document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Do you need to place Knockout.js **custom binding handlers** (not knockout itself but binding handlers) in a jQuery's document.ready or is it safe to assume they will only fire the init and update functions after the DOM has loaded (Knockout will do it for you)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom binding handlers should be registered after Knockout has been loaded, but before `ko.applyBindings` is called, as it is when `ko.applyBindings` is called that the init and update functions of the bindings are called by Knockout (if there is an element in the DOM that is using that particular binding).

The call to `ko.applyBindings` should only happen when the DOM is ready, as explained [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#activating-knockout).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where you load Knockout.  As long as Knockout is loaded you can register binding handlers.

If you are loading Knockout at the footer of your page then it is recommended to use jQuery on load or something similar.

To answer your question on the init and update they will only fire once the DOM is ready and Knockout has combed over it and found your custom binding used in an element.